# mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

Everything worked fine when using a localhost (data insertion and data retrieval worked well) I hosted our website today to develop coding for email activation and so on.

This site is for a computer store, there's a price list of several components categorized neatly. After the site was hosted I get the error:

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a3270569/public_html/products.php on line 92"

I'm not sure why this happens.

Here's my code to retrieve data from one table:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("hostname","username","pass"); //i changed these ;)
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("users",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM intel";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo "<table id=test1 border=1 bgcolor=white>
<tr bgcolor=green>
<th>Processors</th> 
<th>Price</th> 
<th>Warranty</th> 
</tr>";
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){       //this is line 92 in my code
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['war'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You must pass your `$conn` variable to the fetch function

Comment: They're teaching you `mysql_` and not `mysqli_` (or PDO)? Ask your tutor why they're teaching an out of date database extension!

Comment: This is [a very popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid+MySQL+result+resource) - please don't forget to search for error messages (here or in a search engine) prior to asking `:)`.

Comment: Is your database really named `users` but your table named `intel`?

Answer (score 0):

The query probably returns an error.

Add this below `$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);`:

```
if (!$myData){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

This will display the error if the query is invalid.

Edit:

In order to also display errors from `mysql_select_db()`, replace `mysql_select_db("users",$con)` by this:

```
if (!mysql_select_db("users",$con)) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying :)

I get "No database selected"

Not sure why..

Comment: I updated my answer to display more errors.

Comment: It says "Access denied for user 'a3270569_root'@'10.1.1.25' to database 'users'"

Comment: The problem is that `a3270569_root` has no permissions to access the database `users`.

Comment: but that's the username I've given to setup the connection to the database in registering a user too, why doesn't is work here?

Comment: ok i fixed it, the problem was, I have forgotten to use the database name given by the sql manager...it was a3270569_users not users..